# Math help mapping grid to grid. My attempt at a dynamic pathfinding solution, need advice

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, math, coordinates, path-finding

I am working on an AS3 game using Flex and the Flashpunk framework. One of the requirements of this is that I have potentially large numbers of entities moving, colliding, and pathfinding using the A* algorithm.

One of the ways I am attempting to optimize this solution is to have the A* function work from a limited map region composed of a variable grid size around the entity. The entities are limited in their ability to target and path move to another entity via a "sense range" limit.

My idea is I could possibly get away with using A* for dynamic obstacles and goals by only searching over a small area when needed. Once a path is received the entity will move to the first node while checking for collisions. If a collision is detected en route, the entity will wait a second or two, then recheck for collisions. If none are found continue to the node, recheck, move to the next. If after the delay the collision remains, this is most likely a static obstacle and the path should be recalculated.

The problem I'm having deals with the implementation I'm using and how it stores this grid data. Currently the map is being represented by as an array whose length is equal to the grids area. I know this should be moved to a sorted list or binary heap, but I'm keeping it simple until I have something that functions correctly.

**Right, so here's the actual problem:**
[image: Path graph]

This grid represents the search array for an entity at world position 500,500. The entities sprite dimensions are 64x64. The entity is represented as the grey square in the grid center.

The first number in each grid is the index in the array, the second is the row and column (this is how the A* function is storing the array), and the third is the world coordinates relative to the entities position. Each grid block represents an area of 64x64.

I'm attempting to write a grid to world coordinates function. I have a path array that contains the row/column for each node in the path, but I need to convert this to the relative world coordinates. Note the 0,0 coordinate is in the top left.

I've made a few attempts at writing this function with no success, my math is terrible. If anyone has any idea how to accomplish this, or a different approach to this problem, I would be most grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, moving across (left to right) from (0,0), I can go from grid to world by

x_world = 372 + 64*x_grid

And similarly for y

y_world = 372 + 64*y_grid

Does that help?

Comment: Simple and to the point. Seeing this I immediately facepalmed and realized I over-complicated every attempted solution. Unless someone comes in with a better formula or an alternative to my method, by the end of the workday, you've got the selected answer. Thank you very much for reminding me to keep it simple :-P